# How to set end of line in monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Default is CRLF.
I want to change it to LF as i am dealing with BASH scripts.
Please help.

I have gone through the docs but could not find any solution or example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525822/how-to-set-eol-to-lf-for-windows-so-that-api-gets-value-with-n-not-r-n

Answer (score 3):

**`model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF)`**

Usage:

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {});
const model = editor.getModel()
model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF);
editor.getValue();
```

More details: [How to set EOL to LF for windows so that API gets value with \n. not \r\n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525822/how-to-set-eol-to-lf-for-windows-so-that-api-gets-value-with-n-not-r-n/74624712#74624712)

Comment: THANK YOU, the only response on the internet that helped =)

Answer (score 2):

```
//https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/013501950e78b9dde5c2e6ec3f2ddfb9201156b7/src/vs/editor/common/model/pieceTreeTextBuffer/pieceTreeTextBufferBuilder.ts#L30
code = code.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
```

My solution

Comment: Can you explain that further? How to apply this code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setEOL() ? 
I’m also facing the same issue but I’ve used ITextModel interface so can’t used setEOL.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that nightmare, too. It affects shell scripts, and files edited in different OSs.

This is the solution I found when dealing with it using Monaco (and Firepad):

```js
const normalizeLineEndings = (str) => {
    return str?.replace(/\r\n|\r/g, "\n") ?? "";
}

const normalizeEditorModelText = (model, monaco) => {
    if (model.getEndOfLineSequence() === monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF) {
        return;
    }
    // newer Monaco versions recommend pushEOL over setEOL
    model.pushEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF);
    model.applyEdits([
        {
            range: model.getFullModelRange(),
            text: model.getLinesContent().reduce((r, e) => `${r}${normalizeLineEndings(e)}`, "")
        }
    ]);
}

// call it as soon a you create your model
const model = monaco.editor.createModel(text, language);
normalizeEditorModelText(model, monaco);
```

These were the non-sensical errors I dealt with:

- Error: retain expects a positive integer.
- pushOperations() related errors coming from `MonacoAdapter.prototype.operationFromMonacoChanges`

More details on my [GH post](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad/issues/315) (including Firepad's fix).