# How to set EOL to LF for windows so that API gets value with \n. not \r\n

Tags: monaco-editor

I've used monaco.editor.create method for creating model. The problem is monaco is parsing multiline codes into \r\n format in windows OS.

I've tried using defaultEOL as 'LF' in editorOptions in monaco.editor.create()

```
    let editorOptions = {
      value,
      quickSuggestions: { other: true, comments: true, strings: true },
      language: language,
      tabSize: tabSize,

      ...options
    };
    this._editor = monaco.editor.create(this._node, editorOptions);
```

I expect monaco editor to request my API with value \n

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
let textModel = monaco.editor.createModel("");
textModel.setEOL(0);
```

Documentation:

[monaco.editor.createModel](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#createmodel)

[ITextModel.setEOL](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#seteol)

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't get set.

Answer (score 0):

**`model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF)`**

The following example shows on the browser if the Monaco output contains LF or CRLF:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Monaco editor</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<div id="output" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.34.1/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
<script>
const outputElem = document.getElementById('output');
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.34.1/min/vs' }});
require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], () => {
  const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {});
  const model = editor.getModel()
  // model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.CRLF);
  model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLineSequence.LF);
  editor.onDidChangeModelContent(async (e) => {
    outputElem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(editor.getValue());
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm on Ubuntu and by default if I type enter on the editor, I get `\n`.

My goal is to the same as OP but I don't have a Windows machine handy, so I'll just try to change mine to `\r\n`.

If I uncomment the line:

```
model.setEOL(monaco.editor.EndOfLinePreference.CRLF);
```

and comment the `LF` one, I get CRLF, so I think this method works on Windows too.

Thanks to [Henning Dieterichs](https://github.com/hediet) from Microsoft for [pointing out the solution to me](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3440#issuecomment-1346933980).

Bibliography:

- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3440 bug report I opened
- [How to set end of line in monaco-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320218/how-to-set-end-of-line-in-monaco-editor)
- [Monaco Editor newline in getValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655031/monaco-editor-newline-in-getvalue)
- https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react/discussions/247
- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/415b279/website/typedoc/monaco.d.ts#L1705
- https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.editor.EndOfLinePreference.html
- https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.editor.DefaultEndOfLine.html
- https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ITextModel.html

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, Chromium 85 and Firefox 107.